# measuring CPU utilization objectively under load

Tags: performance, cpu-usage

So I have a thread which does some work.  Some of this work is optional and I would like to dynamically adjust how much work is being attempted based on CPU allocation.  In other words I would want to set a configuration knob to "50% of a core" and then my thread would do enough work to keep a core busy half of the time, no more.  My initial idea was to measure the cpu utilization using getrusage and increase or decrease amount of work thread is trying to do based on that.  But then i realized that this is not a reliable measure because if machine gets overloaded my thread running time will drop, but increasing work in this case would not be the right thing at all.
So I need a way to figure out whether the thread is trying to do too much which would not be impacted by how loaded the system as a whole is.

Comment: It's much easier to have a high-priority thread for mandatory work and a low-priority thread for optional work. As it is you're trying to write a scheduler that negotiates indirectly with the kernel scheduler...

Comment: not easily done... i'm doing aggregation of some data and peformance of hash table deteriorates once it gets too big.  I want to define "too big" dynamically based on CPU utilization.

Comment: Is it CPU usage or memory utilisation you want to monitor then? A big hash table doesn't mean high CPU usage. Please clarify.

Comment: @SimonGoater big hash table does mean high CPU usage because there are more items in it with hash code collisions.

Comment: Well, you can tune the *load factor* of the hash table so to reduce the number of collisions. This consumes more memory but there is no free lunch. Besides hash tables are generally not CPU-bound but memory-bound (more specifically latency bound). This overhead can often be mitigated (depending on your *exact* use-case). It looks like a XY problem to me.

Comment: It was an XY problem.  I printed out histogram of the table, realized that some of the buckets had over a 100 entries which was making the insertions be quadratic.  Fixing the hash function made things better.